# Remove URL parameters in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, parameter-passing

My landing page (HTML) communicates with a GWT app via URL with one parameter `login`, so depending on the button you press on the landing page it will redirect to `http://myapp.appspot.com?login=1` (or 2 or 3).

In the GWT app I process that parameter but I need to remove it from URL without reloading the webpage. Is there a way to do this? If not, can I pass this parameter in a different way to my GWT app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you cannot change the parameter without reloading. But your GWT app can read the parameter using [WindowLocation.getParameter](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) and do different things depending on it.