# How to remove a key value from com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location parametermap in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Parameter passed has to be removed or blanked out.

How to remove a key value from `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location` parametermap in GWT

`com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getParameterMap().remove("key")` is not working

Comment: Isn't working means "doesn't remove the key" or "throws an exception"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove URL parameters in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036194/remove-url-parameters-in-gwt)